# How can I quickly tile these command prompts in windows 2012?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-server-2012

I have many command prompt started in one go by a batch file. (16 altogether)

I want to know if there is any easy way to tile these DOS prompt easily via the Windows GUI alone. Preferably into 8 rows and 2 columns

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not rows and columns, but via task manager you can select multiple applications and choose tile vertically, horizontally or cascade...

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11073/stupid-geek-tricks-tile-or-cascade-multiple-windows-in-windows-7/

For more control this looks very interesting, although I haven't tried it myself. But I think I'm about to.
http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/

Comment: This is windows 2012. Not windows 7

Comment: Have you tried selecting two explorer and doing that yourself?